# Chart to deal with about 1000 datapoints

Tags: wpf

In my WPF Application I want to use a chart control to display a number of datapoints,usually about 1000 datapoints, and i want it supports indicator at less. can someone tell me which chart is best.

Comment: define "money". There are good comecial chart controls. Also soem of hose specifically written for financial charts.

Comment: does it need to be interactive? i.e. let the user zoom, scroll, mouseover datapoints etc.

Comment: yes it need to be interactive

Answer (score 4):

Try the opensource OxyPlot project at: http://oxyplot.codeplex.com